# Determine the roots of the equation $(1+xi)^n+(1-xi)^n=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Hello I was trying to solve the equation $$(1+xi)^n+(1-xi)^n=0$$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

I do the following:
$r=\sqrt{1+x^2}$
$1+xi=r(a+bi)=r(\cos{\theta} +i\sin{\theta})$

Then by Moivre's Theorem
$(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})^n=\cos{n\theta}+i\sin{n\theta}$.

Then the equation becomes 
$2\cos{n\theta}=0$

This is OK?

And what about the equation?

Comment: $\LaTeX$ is a bit messed up!

Comment: Is $x$ a real number?

Comment: I assume that $x$ is a complex number.

Comment: `I do the following: r=sqrt(1+x^2) ...` That only holds true if $x$ is a *real* number, and that's where the problem is with your solution.

Comment: OP: Why do you think $x$ is a complex number?  Seems to me, if that were the case, the problem would have just read, for instance, $(1+z)^n+(1-z)^n = 0$.  Multiplying both occurrences of $x$ by $i$, when $x$ is an unknown complex value, seems superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- $x = i$ can be verified not to be a solution, so it's safe to divide by $(1+xi)^n \ne 0$
- with $z = \frac{1-xi}{1+xi}$, the equation becomes $z^n = -1$
- solve the above for $z$, then calculate the corresponding $x = -i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ solutions in $x$

Answer (score 1):

$$
(1+xi)^n +(1-xi)^n = 0 \rightarrow r^n e^{i\theta n}+r^n e^{-i\theta n} = 0 \Rightarrow 2 \cos (n\theta) = 0 
$$
$$
\rightarrow n\theta = (2k+1) \frac{\pi}{2}  | k \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow \theta =\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}
$$

$x\in\mathbb{C}$
$$
\frac{1+xi}{1-xi} = \frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{-i\theta}} \Rightarrow x =\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{e^{2i\theta}-1}{e^{2i\theta}+1} = \frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}} = \frac{2\sin(\theta)}{2\cos(\theta)} = \tan(\theta)
$$

$$
x = \tan \left[\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right] 
$$

Comment: No, it is *not* correct. `tan(θ)=x` That would be the case if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but the OP clarified that `x is a complex number`.

Comment: I proved that  same result holds

Comment: I'll +1 the answer once you remove the `tan(θ)=x` line.

Comment: lol, better? :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

If
$(1+xi)^n+(1-xi)^n=0
$,
then
$(1+xi)^n=-(1-xi)^n
$
so that
$\left(\dfrac{1+xi}{1-xi}\right)^n
=-1
=e^{(2\pi k+\pi) i}
=e^{\pi(2 k+1) i}
$.

Therefore
$\left(\dfrac{1+xi}{1-xi}\right)
=e^{\pi(2 k+1) i/n}
=r(n, k)
$.

Note that there are
only $n$ distinct values of
$r(n, k)$
since
$r(n, k+n)
=e^{\pi(2 (n+k)+1) i/n}
=e^{\pi(2k+1) i/n}e^{\pi(2 n i/n)}
=e^{\pi(2k+1) i/n}e^{\pi2  i)}
=r(n, k)
$.

For each such value,
if we solve
$\dfrac{1+xi}{1-xi}
= r$,
$1+xi
=r(1-xi)
=r-rxi
$
so
$xi(1+r)
=r-1
$
or
$x 
=\dfrac{r-1}{i(r+1)}
=\dfrac{-i(r-1)}{r+1}
$.

To get the real and
imaginary parts of $x$,
with a moderate chance of
making an error
along the way,
I do this:

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{r-1}{r+1}
&=\dfrac{e^{\pi(2 k+1) i/n}-1}{e^{\pi(2 k+1) i/n}+1}\\
&=\dfrac{\cos(t)+i\sin(t)-1}{\cos(t)+i\sin(t)+1}
\qquad\text{where }t = e^{\pi(2 k+1) i/n}\\
&=\dfrac{\cos(t)-1+i\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1+i\sin(t)}
\dfrac{\cos(t)+1-i\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1-i\sin(t)}\\
&=\dfrac{\cos(t)-1+i\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1+i\sin(t)}
\dfrac{\cos(t)+1-i\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1-i\sin(t)}\\
&=\dfrac{\cos^2(t)-\cos(t)+\sin^2(t)+i(\sin(t)(\cos(t)+1)-\sin(t)(\cos(t)-1))}{(\cos(t)+1)^2+\sin^2(t)}\\
&=\dfrac{1-\cos(t)+i(2\sin(t))}{2+2\cos(t)}\\
&=\dfrac{1-\cos(t)+2i\sin(t)}{2(1+\cos(t))}\\
\end{array}
$

This can probably
be expressed more simply
in terms of
$\sin(t/2)$
and
$\cos(t/2)$
and the double angle formula,
but I'll leave it at this.